# Style files for Here Maps 3.1 JS API

Tags: here-api

We're planning to use Here Maps with JS api 3.1 / vector tiles in our project and would like to use styles reduced.day and reduced.night for the web app. The reduced styles are available for some apis, but I cannot find yaml files for those styles.

Are there any other style files available the normal.day and the example dark.yml?

Answer (score -1):

You can download/ save the normal.day yaml file from the [map style editor](https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/#15/52.530903/13.384838). Currently, the normal.day is the only available default style for web. You can also create your own styles with this editor.
You can also use an [example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/styles/change-style-at-load) of the dark theme from our [GitHub](https://github.com/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/tree/master/change-style-at-load/data)

Comment: Thing is when creating a custom style using the new `https://platform.here.com/style-editor` you need to apply your style using the `harp` rendering engine which does not really work (for me) in the javascript API.